# Window on scroll function breaks embedded Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I listen for scrolling on my webpage in order to add a class to my sidebar, to make it position: fixed.

However, I also have a Google-Maps embedded on the same page. Normally, when you scroll over the Map canvas, it shows a grey background with the text 'Use cntrl + scroll to zoom the map'.

The problem is that Google Maps still shows that text, but zooms the map anyway. Tried disabling my scroll-listener, which solved the problem, but I need that function.

My function:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
if (window.pageYOffset > 136) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass("fixed");
} else {
    $('.sidebar').removeClass("fixed");
}
});
```

How can I still use this function and have the Google-Maps embed work normally?

Thanks!

Comment: try using $(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
if (window.pageYOffset > 136) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass("fixed");
} else {
    $('.sidebar').removeClass("fixed");
}
});

Comment: still getting the same issue sadly

Comment: I made a basic example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xilomob/5/edit?html,css,js,output). When I scroll, the sidebar becomes fixed and scrolls down with the page. If I scroll while my cursor is over the map, it displays the message "Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map" and the map itself is not zoomed. Could you adapt the code and paste a link to it here to show the error you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

I think i finally solved it! try this

```
$('body, body *').on('mouseover', function(e) { 
if(e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    currentElement = $(this);
    if (currentElement != Yourgooglemapsellement){
      $(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 136) {
          $('.sidebar').addClass("fixed");
      } else {
          $('.sidebar').removeClass("fixed");
      }
      });          
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: thanks so much for your time! However, still getting the issue. I think it's not registering mouseover on the mapselement correctly (tried adding an 'else{ console.log('map')}'. 
Tried getting the mapselement by $('body').find('#map'); and $('#map'); directly

Comment: Do you have the map in a iframe? If so set id to the iframe and compare currenteElement id to iframe id